# How to erase all text from a file using python, but not delete/recreate the file?

Tags: python

I want to basically copy whats from the clipboard and paste it in a file in utf-8 encoding, but what ever I try, the file has the '?' symbols in it and is Anscii encoding...

But what I found out is, if there is a file that's already in utf-8 encoding, then whatever I paste in it manually (deleting whats there already), wont have the '?' in it.

So if there is a way to clear content in a utf-8 file, then copy whats from the clipboard and write it to that file then that would be great.

If I create the file, it's always ends up being Ancii...

Now I already know how to copy from clip board and write it to a file, its just how to clear a file which is confusing...

Comment: If you open a file for writing, it automatically clears that file...

Such as: open("file.txt", "w")

Comment: Can't you just open the file for writing and truncating (i.e. not appending) and write `utf-8` encoded data to it?

Comment: It might help to mention the operating system and applications you are using for the copy/paste

Comment: I use windows vista, using notepad++

Comment: Possibly notepad++ looks at the content of the file and guesses the encoding. So emptying the file will make it impossible to guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opening the file in write/read mode (`w+`) will truncate the file without rewriting it if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can think of (with my limited knowledge) is to make the file in Python in binary mode, since binaries support UTF-8 encoding:

```
fo=open("file.dat","wb")
# The 'b' flag tells python to make it binary
```

This should work with what you want to do.

To erase the file, just give an existing file name with 'w' and 'b' flags.